# SQL Query - Summarising values, Group by and Having clause

Tags: group-by, having-clause

I have a database table named car with the schema Car(maker, model, type).

I am trying to find a SQL query that finds out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the number of those models exceeds 1.

I am a beginner to SQL and have tried the query

```
select maker, type
from car
group by maker, type
having count(model) > 1
```

But it yields wrong results. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CAPITALISED letters for instructions:
Try this:

```
SELECT maker, type
FROM car
GROUB BY maker, type
HAVING COUNT(model) > 1;
```

And also let's not forget about the semicolon at the end.